# Is bloginfo('template_directory') generated based on WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME in the settings?

Tags: themes, site-url

In my theme, many URLs are generated based on bloginfo('template_directory'), for example, below is a snippet in the header

```
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="64x64" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/apple-touch-icon.png">
```

Now for my site origin.example.com, I have create a Cloudfront distribution xxx.cloudfront.net.

To make sure the URLs in the web pages will use the URLs in xxx.cloudfront.net, not origin.example.com, I modify wp-config.php and add the following lines:

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://xxx.cloudfront.net' );

define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://xxx.cloudfront.net' );
```

However, even after this, when I load a page from https://origin.example.com, I still see this:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="64x64" href="https://origin.example.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/apple-touch-icon.png">
```

So I doubt whether bloginfo('template_directory') is generated based on WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME, or actually based on other values in the database?

I check https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/ and it does not mention that clearly, in the comment there is an example implies that the values comes from WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME.

**Update**

There must be something wrong. I have:

1. Add the following line to wp-config.php:

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'https://xxx.cloudfront.net' );
```

2. Use "Better Search Replace" to replace all origin.example.com with xxx.cloudfront.net.
3. Deactive WP Rocket so that cache will not working.

Even doing all these, my page still use https://origin.example.com/wp-content/themes/xxx/ as the value of bloginfo('template_directory').

Answer (score 0):

The URL used by `bloginfo('template_directory')` is based on various functions that determine the URL to the theme directory, which are ultimately based on the `WP_CONTENT_URL` constant, which is the URL to the `wp-content/` directory.

The initial value for this constant, if you don't define it yourself, is based on the site URL set in the database, in *Settings > General*.

In your case, based solely on your question because I don't really know Cloudfront, you probably want something like this:

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'https://xxx.cloudfront.net/wp-contebt' );
```

As far as I can tell, normally `WP_CONTENT_URL` will use `WP_SITEURL`, but this does not happen on multisite installations, which you must be using.

Comment: Thank you. I think there must be something wrong, I have follow your instructions to add the define statement, I also use Better Search Replace to replace all strings with cloudfront URLs, and I have disactivate the WP Rocket, but my page still use https://origin.example.com/xxx as the bloginfo('template_directory').